# Bronze Badge Not Awarded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I have 100 votes for 43 questions (37 upvoted) which are tagged with [***innodb***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/innodb/topusers).

The last upvote I received on an [innodb-tagged question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323) was 2011-11-11 20:34:27Z.

[My last badge was awarded Oct 20, 2011](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba?tab=activity#page_1-filter_badges).

How long should it take to receive a bronze badge of any type once you reach 100 upvotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's one requirement missing for you to get the badge; see https://dba.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags (emphasis mine):

> If enough votes are earned in **a tag with 100+ total questions**, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

The [innodb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/innodb) tag only has 43 questions at the moment.

Comment: (HOMER SIMPSON) Doh !!! That makes sense. Thank You.

Comment: No need for "Doh" :) To be honest, even I didn't know about this limitation until I explicitly checked because of your question

Comment: Wow, I also didn't realize that. I thought it was points only.